# Call recording, call multiple(repetitive) telephonic stages and creates multiple audio files

Tags: java, android, call, call-recording

I have created one service and broadcast receiver to get telephony state.

Below is my code :

```
 @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        final IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction(ACTION_OUT);
        filter.addAction(ACTION_IN);
        if (br_call == null) {
            br_call = new CallBr();
            registerReceiver(br_call, filter);
        }
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_IN)) {
                if ((bundle = intent.getExtras()) != null) {
                    state =bundle.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
                    Log.d("tag", "state ::" + state);
                    if (!wasRinging) {
                     if(state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {
                            inCall=bundle.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
                            wasRinging = true;
                            Toast.makeText(context, "IN : " + inCall, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                    if(state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)){
                        if (wasRinging) {
                            Toast.makeText(context, "ANSWERED", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            if (recorder == null) {
                                File sampleDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "/RecordingDemo");
                                if (!sampleDir.exists()) {
                                    sampleDir.mkdirs();
                                }
                                String file_name = inCall;
                                try {
                                    audiofile = File.createTempFile(file_name, ".amr", sampleDir);
                                } catch (IOException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                                String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();

                                recorder = new MediaRecorder();
                                recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_CALL);
                                recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB);
                                recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
                                recorder.setOutputFile(audiofile.getAbsolutePath());

                                try {
                                    recorder.prepare();
                                    recorder.start();
                                    recordstarted = true;
                                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                } catch (IOException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)) {
                        wasRinging = false;
                        Toast.makeText(context, "REJECT || DISCONNECT", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        if (recordstarted) {
                            try {
                                recorder.stop();
                                recordstarted = false;
                            } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_OUT)) {
                if ((bundle = intent.getExtras()) != null) {
                    outCall = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);
                    Toast.makeText(context, "OUT : " + outCall, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I am facing below two issues

1) i have printed log in code for different states, but all states are printing multiple times and audio file is also created multiple times for same call.

2) if once i kill the app and start again, many times it wont record any calls. i have to add new build only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I have found a solution. Please try following code.

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        if (intent == null || !ACTION.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
        }
        String state = intent.getStringExtra(STATE);
        String phoneNo = intent.getStringExtra("android.intent.extra.PHONE_NUMBER");
        Log.d("tag", "state: " + state + " phoneNo: " + phoneNo);
        if (OUTGOING.equals(state)) {
            fileNamePrefix = "mob_no_s" + phoneNo + "mob_no_d" + OUTGOING_CALL_SUFFIX;
        } else if (INCOMING.equals(state)) {
            fileNamePrefix = "mob_no_s" + phoneNo + "mob_no_d" + INCOMING_CALL_SUFFIX;
        } else if (BEGIN.equals(state)) {
            if (SecurePreferences.getBooleanPreference(this, Constants.PREF_RECORD_CALLS)) {
                try {
                    startRecording();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        } else if (END.equals(state)) {
            try {
                stopRecording();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else if (STORAGE.equals(state)) {
            if ("mounted".equals(Environment.getExternalStorageState())) {
                prepareAmrDir();
            } else {
                isMounted = false;
            }
            if (!isInRecording) {
                stopSelf();
            }
        }
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    public Context getContext() {
        return cntx;
    }

    private void stopRecording() throws IOException {
        updateNotification(Boolean.valueOf(false));
        if (isInRecording) {
            isInRecording = false;
            try {
                recorder.stop();
                recorder.release();
                recorder = null;
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            releaseWakeLock();
            if (SecurePreferences.getBooleanPreference(this, Constants.PREF_SAVE_RECORDING)) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, AutoRunReceiver.class);
                intent.putExtra("absolutepath", amr.getAbsolutePath());
                sendBroadcast(intent);
            }
            stopSelf();
            Log.d("tag", "call recording stopped");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the broadcast receiver fires multiple times for single event.Debug once and see.

If this is the case use a boolean or little time delay to trigger `onReceive()` only once per event.

Also check with different phone.